# TSQL Function If, Else, or Case

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Ok so I have an assignment for school that is due that states:
Write a function called ShippingCost which will take in values for WeightAmount and WeightType, then
return a dollar amount for shipping cost based on this logic: If the weight is in pounds the shipping is $8
per pound. If the weight is in grams the shipping is $0.03 per gram.
1. If the function is called like this: ShippingCost(2, ‘LB’) it should return 16.00
2. If the function is called like this: ShippingCost(2,’G’) it should return 0.06

I am kind of at a loss on trying to figure out how I do this. This is what I have and it nowhere near being able to work. I dont quite grasp the concept. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

```
Create Function ShippingCost (@ShippingCost DECIMAL (8,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS
    BEGIN
            DECLARE @ShippingCostLB decimal (8,2)
            DECLARE @ShippingsCostG decimal (8,2)
            DECLARE @ShippingWeight decimal (8,2)
            DECLARE @WeightType char (2)
            SET @ShippingCostLB = '8'
            SET @ShippingsCostG = '.03'
            SET @WeightType = ''
            SET @ShippingWeight = ''
    END
                    IF @WeightType = 'LB'
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ShippingCost = @ShippingWeight*@ShippingCostLB
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ShippingCost = [Weight]*@ShippingsCostG
                    END
    RETURN @ShippingCost
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks not even close related to your assignment.

First - it si clearly said your function should take  input values for `WeightAmount` and `WeightType` - so why it takes `ShippingCost` as input and declares `WeightType` as local variable?

Second - what is the purpose of `END` at line 13? In fact, your function will not compile because of unmatched `END` keywords.

The body of function - is very simple condition according to your description, its implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
Create Function ShippingCost (@WeightAmount DECIMAL (8,2), @WeightType char(2))
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @ShippingCost decimal (8,2)

        IF @WeightType = 'LB'
            SELECT @ShippingCost = 8 * @WeightAmount
        ELSE IF @WeightType = 'G'
            SELECT @ShippingCost = 0.03 * @WeightAmount

       RETURN @ShippingCost
END
```

And note that condition (and in your case the whole body of function) can be written in more simple and readable form using `case` statement:

```
Create Function ShippingCost (@WeightAmount DECIMAL (8,2), @WeightType char(2))
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CASE
               WHEN @WeightType = 'LB' THEN 8 * @WeightAmount
               WHEN @WeightType = 'G' THEN 0.03 * @WeightAmount
           END
END
```

Comment: Ok, now seeing how you have set it up I can comprehend where I went wrong (pretty much everywhere). Apparently I didn't quite understand that the input is defined when creating the function. and some of the other nonsense on there was just working and working the question and getting frustrated. I thank you for helping me immensely.